# bash scripting for mysqldump

Tags: bash, mysql

i use the following code to download all mysql database in a different file and not in one file (like --all-databases) and put them in the /backup/mysql folder

```
#!/bin/bash

mysqldump=`which mysqldump`
echo $mysqldump

mkdir /backup/mysql/$(date '+%d-%b-%Y')
echo "creating folder for current date done"


for line in "$(mysqlshow |cut -f1 -d"-" | cut -c 3- | cut -f1 -d" ")"
do

        $mysqldump $line > /backup/mysql/$(date '+%d-%b-%Y')/"$line"
        echo "$line\n"
done
```

I used the cut pipes to remove dashes and empty space before and at the end of the database name and it gave me what I want.

The problem is at line 13 according to bash but with no more details. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

[image: error message]

Comment: You don't need to invoke mysqldump from its full path (otherwise `which mysqldump` would fail). Just write `mysqldump $line > ...`. Furthermore, you should create a variable to store your mysqldump path (i.e., `DB_PATH="/backup/mysql/$(date '+%d-%b-%Y')"`) and use it later in your script (i.e. `mkdir "$DB_PATH"`, `... > "$DB_PATH/$line"`)

Comment: what's the problem bash give you?

Comment: it only say http://prntscr.com/45gv3u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### `mysqlshow` output format

```
+---------------------+
|      Databases      |
+---------------------+
| information_schema  |
| gitlabhq_production |
| mysql               |
| performance_schema  |
| phpmyadmin          |
| test                |
+---------------------
```

Your script doesn't manage the first 3 lines nor the last one, so you `$line` variable is invalid.

### Solution

```
mysql | tail -n +4 | head -n -1 | tr -d '| '
```

- `tail -n +4`: skip first four lines (may need adjustement);
- `head -n -1`: ignore last line ;
- `tr -d '| '`: remove pipe and space.

#### Advices

- [quotes](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes) your variables ;
- [use `$()`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082) instead of backtick ;
- don't use [`for i in $(ls *.mp3)`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29).
- read [How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)

### Better solution

Instead of a `for` loop you should use a `while` with a [Process Substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution):

```bash
while read -r db; do 
  echo "[$db]"; 
done < <(mysqlshow -u root -p | tail -n +3 | head -n -1 | tr -d ' |' )
```

Comment: i adjust a bit so now it is : for line in "$(mysqlshow  | tail -n +5 | head -n -1 | tr -d '| ')" but it give me an error only with dbname
http://prntscr.com/45gyye

Comment: 1) update your question 2) copy/paste in your question 3) try running `bash -x ./your-script.sh`